# Removing css comments with grep

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I'm writing a script that will remove comments from [normalize.css](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/necolas/normalize.css/7.0.0/normalize.css) which looks like this:

```
/*! normalize.css v7.0.0 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in
 *    IE on Windows Phone and in iOS.
 */

html {
  line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * Remove the margin in all browsers (opinionated).
 */
```

I tried with

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

normalize="node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"
if [[ -f "$normalize" ]]; then
  grep -v "\\/\\*([^*]|[\\r\\n]|(\\*+([^*\\/]|[\\r\\n])))*\\*\\/+" $normalize > index.css
else
  echo "There is no normalize.css available."
fi
```

I have loaded the `normalize.css` via `package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "latest"
  }
}
```

You can test this by saving the above `package.json` in a folder and running `npm i`. If you have node and npm you should have `node_modules` folder with normalize in it.

The regex101 finds the comments with above regex, but grep just outputs the same file with comments.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Expected output:

```
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems like `sed` would be much better suited for your problem. You could replace everything that matches `^\/\**\*\/$` with `''`

Comment: is there a particular reason you want to do it with bash and not a minifier via a task runner (grunt, gulp)?

Comment: But `sed` works line by line, so the regex would have to take every possible case in the account, no?

Comment: I need to transform the 'comentless' code some more down the line, so I am using bash, it's quick and relatively easy :)

Comment: Can you post expected output for above css sample. I don't have `npm`

Comment: Added the expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command to remove all css comments that start with `/*` and end with `*/`:

```
cat remComm.awk

function remComm() {
   if ( !m )
      m = index($0, cs);

   if ( m && p = index($0, ce) ) {
      $0 = substr($0, 1, m-1) substr($0, p+2);
      if (m = index($0, cs))
         remComm();
   }
}
BEGIN {
   cs="/*";
   ce="*/";
   m = 0;
}
{
   remComm();
   if ( !m && NF )
      print;
}
```

Use it as:

```
awk -f remComm.awk normalize.css
```

**Output:**

```
html {
  line-height: 1.15;
  -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

- This is non regex solution so should process big files faster.
- This also takes care of nested comments and presence of multiple comment block per line.
- We set start position of comment when we encounter `/*` and get end position when get `*/` in the file.
- Using `substring` functions we strip off commented positions and leave rest in `$0`
- function `remComm` is called recursively to remove multiple comments per line.
- Using `!NF` we skip printing blank or whitespace lines.

Comment: The first version worked, the second one fails on the `cat remComm.awk` command (`cat: remComm.awk: No such file or directory`)

Comment: No no, you have to copy/paste given below `cat` script and save it as `remComm.awk`. Then run the `awk` command as shown.

Comment: Oh I see. And what is the benefit of that over the first solution?

Comment: This updated script also removes multiple comment block per line.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!